# InfoPath Designer - Largest Field Size

Tags: infopath, column, size

What is the largest field size that can be created in InfoPath Designer and is it a Text field or a Memo Field or something else?

Comment: Multiple lines of text would be the largest in terms of available text input if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose "Plain List" in the feild or "Bulleted List"in the feild and where the person types or adds anything and it just keeps on getting larger and larger on the same screen wrapping the text with the click of the space bar, rather than spreading to the side like the regular text feild does. I just tested it and it seems like the size is infinte.